# Punctuation: is this usage of a semicolon correct?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

The sentence:

> First of all, i just want to state that these are really great; I wish i had known about them earlier.

It would be great if you could also add some overall tips on the usage of semicolons as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct usage of a semicolon.

There are many great websites that can give you some good tips on how to use semicolons.  [Here are two common usages of the semicolon provided by the Writing Center at the University of Wisconsin-Madison.](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html)

**Link two independent clauses to connect closely related ideas**

This is what you have done in your example. You can link two complete sentences that are related using a semicolon if you want to emphasize that they are connected.

> Some people write with a word processor; others write with a pen or
> pencil.

**Link lists where the items contain commas to avoid confusion between list items**

It can often be difficult to create a list inside a sentence, so a semicolon can help to break up the sentence and make sure your ideas are easily understood.  Two examples they provide of this are:

> 1. There are basically two ways to write: with a pen or pencil, which is
>    inexpensive and easily accessible; or by computer and printer, which
>    is more expensive but quick and neat.
> 2. I like cows: they give us milk, which tastes good; they give us beef,
>    which also tastes good; and they give us leather, which is used for
>    shoes and coats.

---

Another helpful tip they provide is on when to use a common vs. a semicolon.  If you are connecting two independent clauses and you do NOT have a coordinating conjunction, you need a semicolon.  If there is a coordinating conjunction, you need a comma. (Coordinating conjunctions: and, but, or, nor, so, yet...)

> The cow is brown; it is also old.
>
> The cow is brown, and it is also old.

Be careful, 'however' is not a coordinating conjunction.  Many people incorrectly use a common before however.

> Incorrect: I like cows, however, I hate the way they smell.
>
> Correct: I like cows; however, I hate the way they smell.

In addition, if one of the clauses is not independent, you must use a common.

> Because cows smell, they offend me.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! I am not marking it as "correct" immediately because i want some sort of competition. If this remains as the best answer tomorrow, i will mark it as "correct".  
  
And lastly, you couldn't put a semicolon before "i will mark it as 'correct'" and "you couldn't put a semicolon before" because the preceding statements are not complete sentences, right ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second example, but you are correct about the first example.  "If this remains as the best answer tomorrow" is not a complete sentence, so you need a comma.  "I will mark it as correct" is a complete sentence, so you could use a semicolon to add a complete sentence before or after it. An example: "I will mark it as correct; it is the best answer."  BUT "I will mark it as correct; you couldn't put a semicolon before 'I will' " is incorrect because the two sentences are not directly related.

~~ P.S. Thank you. :)

Comment: It appears that i don't know how to print out white-space in a Stackexchange comment, sorry. In the second example, i was talking about putting a semicolon between `And lastly` and `you couldn't put a semicolon before...`; by now, i am sure that you can't though. Thank you as well!

Comment: You are absolutely correct.